# How to make tuple of this list- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, tuples

I am new to Python.
I have a List -

```
a=[{'name':'Anurag','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2345','resources':[{'resource':'www.coob.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'rohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2346','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'purohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2347','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}}]
```

I want to have a list of tuple like this -

```
[
(Anurag,KT2345,www.coob.com),
(Anurag,KT2345,www.buj.com),
(Anurag,KT2345,www.cademy.com),
(Anurag,KT2345,www.zxt.com),
(rohit,KT2346,www.coob1.com),
(rohit,KT2346,www.buj1.com),
(rohit,KT2346,www.cademy1.com),
(rohit,KT2346,www.zxt1.com),
(purohit,KKT2347,www.coob2.com),
(purohit,KT2347,www.buj2.com),
(purohit,KT2347,www.cademy2.com),
(purohit,KT2347,www.zxt2.com)
]
```

I tried various things like:

```
for v in a:
   for key,value in v.items():
```

I am unable to get it in the required format.

Comment: Simply use the key values iterate over to each key-value pairs and write them into tuple. The assumption is that the dictionary that is being obtained is in an ordered way.

Comment: name = value['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You say you have tried various things, what exactly where they, and how did they not work?

Comment: @anuragkumaranu added the answer with few assumptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```py
result = []

for i in a:
    sub = []
    sub.append(i['name'])
    sub.append(i['assignedTopics']['concept_id'])
    for res in i['assignedTopics']['resources']:
        sub2 = sub.copy()
        sub2.append(res['resource'])
        result.append(tuple(sub2))

print(result)
```

Comment: sub.append(i['assignedTopics']['concept_id'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: The object `a` was used with the example provided. If you are running the code against some other data, it may a different structure. Ensure your example snippet also contains anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
a=[{'name':'Anurag','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2345','resources':[{'resource':'www.coob.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'rohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2346','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'purohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2347','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}}]

result = []
for x in a:
    for y in x['assignedTopics']['resources']:
        result.append((x['name'], x['assignedTopics']['concept_id'], y['resource']))

for x in result:
    print(x)
# ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.coob.com')
# ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.buj.com')
# ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.cademy.com')
# ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.zxt.com')
# ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.coobo1.com')
# ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.buj1.com')
# ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.cademy1.com')
# ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.zxt1.com')
# ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.coobo2.com')
# ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.buj2.com')
# ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.cademy2.com')
# ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.zxt2.com')
```

You just need to keep track of all the containers of the input.

Comment: Thanks! But Order changes after every iteration of 1st for loop.

Comment: Which version of Python are you in? If in Python 3.6 or higher, the above code must work. Otherwise you can use `sorted()` with an appropriate `key` to get to the order you wish. Without further explanation on your end (e.g. what order you need), I am afraid I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

This should do for you:
Assuming that the output is in the below format and keys:

```
a=[{'name':'Anurag','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2345','resources':[{'resource':'www.coob.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'rohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2346','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt1.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}},{'name':'purohit','assignedTopics':{'concept_id':'KT2347','resources':[{'resource':'www.coobo2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.buj2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.cademy2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'},{'resource':'www.zxt2.com','typeform':'www.typeform.com'}]}}]

list_tuples=[]
for val in a:
    name = val["name"]
    assigned_topic = val["assignedTopics"]["concept_id"]
    res_list = val["assignedTopics"]["resources"]
    for val in res_list:
        list_tuples.append((str(name), str(assigned_topic), str(val["resource"])))
```

Output:

```
list_tuples
Out[38]: 
[('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.coob.com'),
 ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.buj.com'),
 ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.cademy.com'),
 ('Anurag', 'KT2345', 'www.zxt.com'),
 ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.coobo1.com'),
 ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.buj1.com'),
 ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.cademy1.com'),
 ('rohit', 'KT2346', 'www.zxt1.com'),
 ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.coobo2.com'),
 ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.buj2.com'),
 ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.cademy2.com'),
 ('purohit', 'KT2347', 'www.zxt2.com')]
```